# Calculating a Percent from Values in the Same Field

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server. I have a nice summary table like the one you see below. I want to populate (create) the Pct field for each proficiency level.

```
| MeasurementScale | Grade | ProficiencyLevel | PL_Count | Pct |
|------------------|-------|------------------|----------|-----|
| Mathematics      |   6   | Did Not Meet     |    40    |     |
| Mathematics      |   6   | Approaches       |    86    |     |
| Mathematics      |   6   | Meets            |    83    |     |
| Mathematics      |   6   | Masters          |    42    |     |
| Mathematics      |   6   | Total            |   251    |     |
```

I basically want something like the following query, I just don't know how to write it.

```
SELECT SchoolName
      ,MeasurementScale
      ,Grade
      ,ProficiencyLevel 
      ,PL_Count
      ,(PL_Count / (SELECT PL_Count FROM #PL_Summary1920 WHERE ProficiencyLevel = 'Total')) as Pct
FROM #PL_Summary1920
GROUP BY SchoolName
        ,MeasurementScale
        ,Grade
        ,ProficiencyLevel 
        ,PL_Count
```

Comment: Have you got any error or what is your problem?

Comment: That example script I posted errors out because the subquery returns more than one value.

Comment: @Scottgman please explain the relations of `#PL_Summary1920` and the results you show in your question. I though that with `SUM(PL_Count)` should work, it seems by the other answers, is not.

Comment: Marco: not sure what you mean by "relations"-- but this is just a summary table I aggregated from a student-level data file. I could probably calculate the percentages in the same step that I'm creating this summary table... I'm just not that good with SQL... haha.

Comment: @Scottgman my bad, I thought it was two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  V1.*,
        CASE WHEN V2.PL_COUNT = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE V1.PL_Count * 1.0/ V2.PL_COUNT
        END AS  PCT
FROM    (
            SELECT  SchoolName,
                    MeasurementScale,
                    Grade,
                    ProficiencyLevel,
                    SUM(PL_Count)   AS  PL_Count
            FROM #PL_Summary1920 T1
            GROUP BY SchoolName
                    ,MeasurementScale
                    ,Grade
                    ,ProficiencyLevel 
        ) V1
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT  SchoolName,
                        MeasurementScale,
                        Grade,
                        SUM(TT.PL_Count)    AS  PL_COUNT
                FROM    #PL_Summary1920 TT
                WHERE   TT.ProficiencyLevel = 'Total'
                GROUP BY SchoolName,
                        MeasurementScale,
                        Grade
            ) V2 ON V2.SchoolName = V1.SchoolName
                    AND V2.MeasurementScale = V1.MeasurementScale
                    AND V2.Grade = V1.Grade
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT MeasurementScale
  ,Grade
  ,ProficiencyLevel 
  ,PL_Count
  ,PL_Count * 1.0 / (SELECT PL_Count FROM #PL_Summary1920 WHERE ProficiencyLevel = 'Total') as Pct 
FROM #PL_Summary1920
GROUP BY SchoolName
    ,MeasurementScale
    ,Grade
    ,ProficiencyLevel 
    ,PL_Count
```

Doing the multiplication by 1.0 forces a type conversion to decimal, so your percentages display correctly. It's cleaner than doing a CAST or CONVERT.

Comment: Thanks Michael. My example query doesn't work because the subquery returns more than 1 value. I think a join would solve this I just don't know how to write it.

Comment: For the sub-query, try these instead:


`(SELECT TOP 1 PL_Count FROM #PL_Summary1920 WHERE ProficiencyLevel = 'Total')`

Or:


`(SELECT SUM(PL_Count) FROM #PL_Summary1920 WHERE ProficiencyLevel <> 'Total')`

Comment: That's close! The SELECT TOP 1 worked for the first group (math grade 6) but after that it does not calculate the percent correctly I think because it's not accounting for the Group By. In other words,the percentages for math grade 7, math grade 8, etc. are not correct.

Comment: Based on the data set you posted, I didn't see the other grades.

It might help, then, to calculate the sums grouped by grade in a separate CTE (Common Table Expression) above your main query, then join your main query to the CTE.

`WITH GradeSums AS (
SELECT Grade, SUM(PL_Count) FROM #PL_Summary1920 WHERE ProficiencyLevel <> 'Total'
)`

I don't have the room to include the rest of the query, but that should get you started.